# How Do I Compute Orbits Using Runge-Kutta in C# Over Multiple Timesteps?

Tags: c#, physics, runge-kutta

As part of a project I'm working on, I need to simulate the orbits of an object around a star using a 4th order Runge-Kutta method. I need to write the position and velocity of this object to a .dat file for each implementation of the RK4 method.

My problem is that I can't work out how to repeat the entire method over subsequent time intervals or how to write to file at each step without confusing things with statics and/or instances, which I don't have much experience with.

[This](http://www.letsthinkabout.us/post/runge-kutta-in-c) was the most coherent example I could find* and while I know it isn't for orbits, I wanted to use it as a basis to get the framework working. When everything works, I imagine I'll change its contents to something more like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357974/integrating-differential-equations-of-motion-for-orbit-in-runge-kutta-in-c).

To write to .dat, I've modified the example's Run() function to:

```
        public void Run()
    {
        while (x < target) {
            y = RungeKutta.rk4(x, y, dx, dy_dt);
            x += dx;
        }
        print("x = " + x + ", y = " + y);
        DataLine = x + " " + y;
        DustHandler.DataWriter();
    }
```

where DataLine is a public static string.

I then included in my main script the following functions:

```
//  void Update() {
//      if(Input.GetButtonDown("Space")==true) {
//          Transformers.Equation e = new Transformers.Equation(Transformers.Equation.x, Transformers.Equation.y, 0.0001, 1.0);
//          e.Run();
//      }
//  }

public static void DataWriter() {
    using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter("Orbit.dat"))
    {
        writetext.Write(Transformers.Equation.DataLine);

        writetext.Close();
    }   
}
```

Now, DataWriter() works fine, but as soon as I un-comment Update(), I get all kind of problems related to how it's calling the data. So I go in, try to make whatever it is static, but then everything else goes haywire. I don't know if using instances instead would fix it and I'm not familiar with how they work at all.

Is there a more obvious solution I'm overlooking here? I'd be grateful for any help on the matter. (Incidentally, could anyone clarify what the example's target/dy_dt actually means?)

* I originally tried Numerical Recipes in C but it seemed hopelessly out of date and I'm more rusty with C than I had thought.

Comment: Note that the code that you found is wrong, as it uses both `dx` as factor of the slope and `halfdx` inside the arguments in `k2` and `k3`. This means that effectively the second argument in the computation of `k2` is `y+0.5*dx*dx*f(x,y)`.

Comment: @LutzL I noticed that they used `dx` instead of `dt` for their timestep and that threw me off a little. But yes, I can see the error there. It still throws out some numbers, though, and the main thing I'm trying to solve is writing the data/repeating the process, after which I'll be replacing the original equations with orbital ones and correcting the `k` values. Thank  you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue just by putting everything in the same script and class. It works, but seems like a cheaty way to do it.